# How to filter zero-prices products end of list?

Tags: price, sorting

I want all of the zero-priced products for different filtering options (Name etc) to end of list (search page and category product list). For example product sorted by name arrange the products in alphabetical order, but if product price is zero it should be last of list even if name of the product start with a letter A.

What is the best way to do this feature?

Answer (score 1):

In category page, products collections sorting is taking place in `Toolbar-block` (*Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar*).

According to the analysis that I have carried out in core files, I noted that sorting request is invoked by the `List-block` (*Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List*). Take a look on the file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php`, specifically in `_beforeToHtml()` method. You can see this calling

```
 // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
    $toolbar->setCollection($collection);
```

Sorting of product collection is carried out by this method. Now take a look on `setCollection()` method, which is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`

```
 <?php
 public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, `setOrder()` method does the magic. Now we need an additional sorting along with default one. That is based on price of product. For that just change

```
  $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
```

to this

```
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection())
                 ->setOrder('price','desc');
```

That's it. That will do the necessary ordering based on price.

You can achieve this by directly editing `Toolbar.php`.

However it is not a good practice. Try to make a module that overwrites `setCollection()` method  inside `Toolbar.php`. Thus magento core files become untouched and we will get the desired result.

### EDIT

An alternative method is placing `Toolbar.php` block inside `local` codePool. For this copy content of default `Toolbar.php` to this location

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

and make changes to this file accordingly. This will work because, `local` codePool has higher priority than `core` codePool. So for a file, Magento will first look in `local` codePool, then `community`, `core` and `lib`. 
Good Luck.

Comment: Please add a part about copying the file to `app/code/local` before editing it :-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt:  edited answer as per your request.. Personally I don't like that method :-)

Comment: No one does. The alternative is rewriting. And in THIS case, you can greatly use an observer. So if you want to describe this way too, feel free to post a second answer :D - Thanks for the edit (I should have it done - damn idiot me) Was not the time yesterday to get the idea to do it myself ^^

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt : yep. that is not at all a problem. You can review my answers as much as you need. I personally love to hear what other devs think about my answers. So PING ME ALWAYS !!!

Comment: You see it, when I edit it too, so less work for you and editing is "as much work" as writing a comment - stop chatting here. If you have more, ping me on twitter ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use local rather then over riding core file:

> app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

Update `setCollection($collection)`

```
public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
           $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection())
                 ->setOrder('price','desc');
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: But I personally hate the `local` trick. I always go for rewrite. We can do some compromise for a rewrite according to the circumstances. But the local way cannot be modified in any manner. Also it makes some problems while upgrading mageto :-)